# Set other value other than default value in angular 7 dropdown

Tags: angular7, dropdown

I have a drop-down list where it shows 'US' as a default value which
    is right but suppose a user 
        is from India so Instead of this i want 'India' in the drop-down.If user is from 'US' or any 
        other country then it shows 'US' in the drop-down.
        So i want to store the current location of the user in the drop-down.But
        By default it should shows 'US' in the drop-down. If the user is from 
        India then set 'India' in the drop-down.

Simply if a user is from 'US' or any other country then by default it shows 
  'US' in the drop-down but if the user is from 'India' then it shows India in 
   the drop-down.

app.component.ts -

```
   countries = [
    { name: 'USA', id: '0' },
    { name: 'India', id: '1' }
];

 public onChange() {
    const userCountry = sessionStorage.getItem(this.appConstants.StorageKeys.UserCountry);
    if (userCountry !== null || userCountry !== '') {
        return userCountry;
        console.log(userCountry);
    } else {
        return this.countries;
    }
}

Here userCountry gives the current location of user i.e; India , Us, OR Any 
other country that we fetch from the api .
```

app.component.html

```
<select (click)="onChange()">
<option  *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">{{ country.name }} 
</option>      
</select>
```

What should i do in the app.component.html to bind when the current location of the user is 
    India or any other country.
    Also i don't want to use ngModel for binding.
    Kindly Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

```
   countries = [
           { name: 'USA' },
           { name: 'India'}
        ];

   public selectedCountry: string = 'India';      

   <select>
   <option  *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country" 
   [selected]="country === selectedCountry">
   {{ country }}
   </option>
   </select>

   For reactive form use syntax for drodown -

  <select>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country }}" 
  selected="country === {{selectedCountry}}">{{ country }}
  </option>
  </select>
```

[For Another way of dropdown binding reactive form you can also visit-](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor)
      Using select controls in a reactive form
      The following examples show how to use a select control in a reactive form.

```
  import {Component} from '@angular/core';
  import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

  @Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
   <select formControlName="state">
    <option *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state">
      {{ state.abbrev }}
    </option>
   </select>
  </form>

 <p>Form value: {{ form.value | json }}</p> 
 <!-- {state: {name: 'New York', abbrev: 'NY'} } -->
  `,
 })
export class ReactiveSelectComp {
states = [
{name: 'Arizona', abbrev: 'AZ'},
{name: 'California', abbrev: 'CA'},
{name: 'Colorado', abbrev: 'CO'},
{name: 'New York', abbrev: 'NY'},
{name: 'Pennsylvania', abbrev: 'PA'},
];

form = new FormGroup({
 state: new FormControl(this.states[3]),
 });
}
```